# Subtraction and borrowing for dummies

Tags: arithmetic, education

Regarding the subtraction and borrowing a digit from upper digits, I know how that works for more than one digit numbers. However, I can not figure out for one digit numbers! It is an obvious thing since we were in school. But I need a mathematically explanation.

Example:

What is the result of 21-13?

```
 2 (10^1)       1 (10^0)
-1 (10^1)      -3 (10^0)
________________________
```

For the first digit, we know that `1<3`, so we have to borrow from the next digit. The next digit is `2*10` and the borrowed value will be 10. Therefore, the first number is changed to `1 (10^1)      (10+1) (10^0)`. Now we are able to subtract `3` from `11` and then `1` from `1`. The results will be `8`

Problem:

Now assume, we want to find the result of `1-3` with the above mentioned methodology. We know that

```
 0 (10^1)        1 (10^0)
-0 (10^1)       -3 (10^0)
_________________________
```

We have to borrow a `10` from the second digit but it is `0`. There is also no more **non-zero** digit in the left (all left digits are zero means 0...000001).

So how we reach `1-3=-2`??

**UPDATE**

According to the comments and answers, borrowing is not a universal method and may fail if there is no 1 in the left. The question now is, what is the universal method for subtraction?

Comment: The usual way is just to recognize that $1-3 = -(3-1)$ so we can always just subtract the bigger number (in absolute value terms) from the smaller and then add a negative sign at the end if needed.

Comment: The borrowing rule simply does not apply when you want to make a subtraction $x-y$ with $x<y$.

Comment: Simple: you don't use this method for single digits. This method isn't exactly a sophisticated mathematical algorithm or anything- it's just a heuristic taught in middle school. For $1-3 = -2,$ the same teachers who taught us that same heuristic also taught us to move "one unit right" on the  1-D number line, and then "3 units left" to land on -2.

Comment: @Crostul That's not accurate. Borrowing still works. It just can't be applied to this problem.

Comment: If you think about it, the borrowing method gives the answer as $-10+8$. Which is correct, it's just not in simplest terms.

Comment: @Crostul: So what is the universal methodology for subtraction?

Comment: @mahmood If $x\ge y$, compute $x-y$ (using borrowing). If $x<y$, compute $-(y-x)$ (use borrowing for $y-x$ and stick a minus sign in front).

Comment: @mahmood I think computers do something fancier called "ten's complements," which is yet another method. (Or, rather, two's complements, since they work in binary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way to get to an answer. The borrowing method is just one method.

As it happens, the borrowing method isn't particularly useful for $1-3$. (We have nothing to borrow from!) So we use another method.

On thing we can do is notice that:
$$(1-3)+(3-1)=0$$
(Just remove the parentheses. Everything cancels.) Now, any two things that add up to zero are opposites of each other! That means that $(1-3)=-(3-1)$, or $1-3=-(2)=-2$.

In general, $x-y=-(y-x)$. If you ever have to subtract a large number from a smaller one, just switch them around and put a minus sign in front.

Comment: (Some of you may notice how I've been influenced by group theory in my second-to-last paragraph.)

Comment: This answer is OK. But you said in the comments that borrowing still works for one digits.

Comment: @mahmood I said, "Borrowing still works. It just can't be applied to this problem."

Comment: OK I saw your last comment in the OP

Comment: @mahmood We want $1-3$. Borrow the $10$ from nothing (we'll deal with it later) and give it to the $1$, changing it to $11$. Now we are able to subtract $3$ from $11$ to get $8$. But we borrowed $10$ from nothing, so we have to subtract it out agin. The total is $8-10$. But, as I said, this isn't particularly helpful.

Comment: Borrowing won't work for some non-uni-digit numbers. Can  you explain 11-15 with borrowing?

Comment: Sure. Still won't give a good answer, though. Borrow ten from the $1$ on the left (changing it to $0$) and give it to the $1$ on the right (changing it to $11$). In the ones' column, subtract $11-5=6$. In the tens' column, we want to subtract $0-1$. Won't work. Borrow a ten (which I'll subtract off at the end), changing the $0$ to a $1$. Now, in the tens' column, subtract $1-1=0$. We now have $06$ as the answer. Subtracting the $10$ I stole, we have $6-10$ as the (correct but unhelpful) answer.

Comment: Still my question is what is the universal method for subtract?

Comment: I'll say again: "If $x\ge y$, compute $x-y$ (using borrowing). If $x<y$, compute $-(y-x)$ (use borrowing for $y-x$ and stick a minus sign in front)."